# Вылетает программа, при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.6

Импортирую 2 файла в которых GUI окон. Потом пытаюсь создать дочернее окно путем нажатия на кнопку в меню. Приложение закрывается. Что я делаю не так? Укажите пожалуйста на ошибку.

```
import sys
from Passgen import *
from about import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.menuInfo.triggered.connect(self.create_window)

    def create_window(self):
        self.second_window = Second_window (self)
        self.second_window.show ()


class Second_window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__ (self, parent)
        self.second_window = Second_window ()
        self.second_window.setupUi (self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = Window()
    application.show()
    sys.exit (app.exec_ ())
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста модули Passgen.py и about.py

Comment: https://gist.github.com/TRT360/0723a24d12a972430d80206ee0cd21c2/revisions

Comment: Дело в том, что с этими модулями у меня все прекрасно работало, когда я вместо создания нового окна about.py изменял содержимое главного окна Passgen.py на тот же about.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас проблема с именами:

```
import sys
from Passgen import Ui_MainWindow             #*
from about   import Second_window             #*
from PyQt5   import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.menuInfo.triggered.connect(self.create_window)

    def create_window(self):
#        self.second_window = Second_window(self) 
        self.second_window = SecondWindow(self)       # SecondWindow
        self.second_window.show ()


class SecondWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):             # SecondWindow
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__ (self, parent)

        self.second_window = Second_window ()
        self.second_window.setupUi (self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = Window()
    application.show()
    sys.exit (app.exec_ ())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]